# SSL Termination on NGINX

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have purchased an SSL cert and bundled it up correctly in so much as when I verify the modulus (i.e. https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/4064) then the hashes are the same.

I have moved the cert and key to my server @ /etc/ssl and ensured that the folder permissions are 700 and each file is 600.

I have then the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   443 ;
    server_name escapehatch.chrisjowen.uk;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/secret.txt;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}
```

Finally, to test this, I have a Python SimpleHTTPServer running on port 8080. When I hit the URL on HTTPS, I receive an error

> This site can’t provide a secure connection

Looking at the logs from the Python server, I see:

```
218.186.183.142 - - [21/Aug/2019 04:45:53] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xfc\x03\x03\x01a\x96\x061LE\x88I\xf1i\x7f\xc3\xdc%d\x18r\xbbzq9q<\xeb\x1dD\xa3\x8b\x01\x10\x7f')
218.186.183.142 - - [21/Aug/2019 04:45:53] "�a�1LE�I�i��%dr�zq9q<�D�� n��Z���΀��SN�F���j;X.Zw�s^�"**�+�/�,�0̨̩����/5" 400 -
218.186.183.142 - - [21/Aug/2019 04:45:53] code 400, message Bad request version ('\x0fb\x03g\x8d\x04\x8b\xbe!\xad\x98W\x9bV\xd2\x8e\x1e\xc6\xf3\xaa\xff\xce\x0f\x1b\xc9\x0f\xebY\xae\xc4\x00"\xfa\xfa\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xc0+\xc0/\xc0,\xc00\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xc0\x13\xc0\x14\x00\x9c\x00\x9d\x00/\x005\x00')
```

So, it seems like nginx is not decrypting the request and terminating the SSL connection, instead it's passing it to the upstream server, which I do not want.

Checking the nginx logs /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log shows nothing.

So, now I am stumped what to do to debug the issue, it appears that either nginx config is wrong or there is something wrong with the cert, but as mentioned I checked this with the following method https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/4064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> listen   80;
> listen   443 ;
> ```

If you want it to listen for plain http on port 80 and https on port 443 the second line should be `listen 443 ssl;`.

> ```
> ssl    on;
> ```

From [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl):

> This directive was made obsolete in version 1.15.0. The ssl parameter of the listen directive should be used instead.

Also you have the following in the logs of your Python server:

> ```
> 218.186.183.142 - - [21/Aug/2019 04:45:53] code 400, ....
> ```

This Python server is clearly visited directly by an external IP address. If the request would be forwarded by the local nginx then the source IP should be 127.0.0.1 instead. This shows, that you don't hit nginx at all but somehow make a direct request to the Python server.

Comment: Thanks but this issue remains after this change. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Owen: Are you sure that you are actually connecting with your client to nginx and not directly to the python server? You only say "When I hit the url on HTTPS" but not which URL you are actually using. You should not use `https://localhost:8080` but you should use `https://your.domain` (without port, so that the default 443 gets used).

Comment: Yes of course I am not trying to hit localhost, I am hitting the url as per the config https://escapehatch.chrisjowen.uk

Comment: @Owen: I get a "Connection refused" on this URL, i.e. even the TCP connect fails which means it will not even hit your nginx.

Comment: @Owen: Your information that you don't see anything in the nginx log files suggests to me that you are not hitting nginx - or at least not the part of the configuration where you are looking at the logs. Also, the log files of your Python server show that the request is not coming from 127.0.0.1 as it would be expected if it got forwarded by nginx. Instead it is coming from some external IP address as it happens only if the request is not forwarded by a local reverse proxy.

Comment: @Owen: So how to do you explain the non-local source IP address in the logs from your python server? If you are hitting nginx it should be 127.0.0.1 and not some external IP. Also, I don't say that you don't hit the nginx when using plain http on port 80. The problem you have is with https on port 443.

Comment: @Owen: Right now I can to a successful plain HTTP request __to port 443__ on your server which then gets forwarded to your Python server according to the `Server` string. But the expected HTTPS on this port does not work. This suggests, that SSL is not properly enabled on port 443 in your nginx. If you still use `listen 443` instead of `listen 443 ssl` then this might be the cause.

Comment: I owe you an apology, there was indeed something redirecting traffic from 8080 > 443 prior to nginx been hit. It was all so confusing as I had the nginx config to do exactly the same and as such I was so certain that it was nginx itself doing this. I apologize for my abruptness and feel humbled at my stupidity